# Jquery Mobile input issue

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Am working with jquery mobile 1.4.4 and some inputs on my views only lets type one character:

[image: On android]

[image: On iOS]

Many sites suggest me that apply the next style on all inputs and textAreas

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
```

But it doesn´t work. I test on android 4.1.2, 4.2.2, iOS 6.

Any help with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: how is your markup defined ?

Comment: <input type="text" name="customerName" data-mini="true"    placeholder="Nombre y apellido" class="required" data-bind="value:customer.name()">

Comment: I use knockout to data binding

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by removing the following from the CSS (was only breaking on the iPhone)

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```